# Exploring / editing SQL Server data of a runtime installation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I installed some software which has built into its installer a sort of minimal installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. The software itself uses the database just fine, but I want somehow to be able to access the database directly by myself, using some GUI.

How can I add some GUI tool that will allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need SQL Express with Tools, that will give you Management Studio Express.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26729

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following download http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3990.  Once downloaded you'll need permissions to the db and I'd suspect you won't have the pw for the SA account.  At this point things become risky if you can clone the system first do it.  Use the steps from this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322336.  good luck

Comment: this doesn't seem to have a GUI for inspecting the tables - does it?

Comment: Use the one linked by @danbig, the real issue will be getting access to the db as in what accounts does it use sql vs domain etc..